# Multiple Image Uploading / Map Images to Products

Tags: c#, asp.net, image-processing, image-uploading

I am looking for a solution (APIs, etc.) for handling a similar experience as cafepress.com.  I need to be able to upload images (preferably multiple at a time) and be able to map my uploaded images to various product images (clean stock images of shirts, mugs, etc.).  I also want to give the user some very basic controls over the images they upload such as cropping, resizing, levels, etc.  Any suggested libraries or APIs would be greatly appreciated.  I am looking for .NET solutions (if server-side).  I am not looking for how to tie this all together but rather some suggested libraries or tools to build out some of this functionality.

*Note:  If this is not the place for this type of question, please move accordingly or suggest an alternate site.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frankly, I don't think you are going to find what you are looking for specifically, unless you are looking at using a full on CMS of some form.  Frankly, those problem domains are too far apart.  Instead you should probably look at them as individual pieces.

So far as upload controls exist, there are probably close to 100, some free some not so free.  Personally, I already have a Telerik subscription, so it was a no-brainer for me, but [Rad Upload](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/upload/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx) works well and supports multiple uploads.  Free implementations are available.

The cropping and post image handling tasks ( at least the ones you have listed ), can easily be handled using standard System.Drawing.* calls, or if it gets more advanced a ton of free libraries exist, like the age old [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php), but there are a number of commerical libraries available as well.  Chances are though, the inbuilt libraries will be more than sufficient.

Finally the mapping to products should be handled by your business layer ( aka, code you write ) as it is going to be so specific to your app.

However, if you are looking for a storefront or CMM with a multiple image upload control, that is a very different question with many options as well, both free and commercial.

Answer (score 1):

use openCV. you can find it here: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/
you can use this library perfectly with c++.
if you need to use it in C# use this wrapper: www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page